"Cyclical polynomials"
I'm not sure what to call them but I'm looking for some information for polynomials which are "Cyclical" in nature.
A polynomial expanded by factors: $\prod (x - a_k)$ is based on combinations/permutations since $\prod (x - a_k) = \sum x^k \sum \prod a_l$ where the inner sum-prod is over combinations.
I am interested in polynomials where we only allow indices that are circular:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} x^k \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \prod_{l=0}^{k-1} a_{l + j} = \sum \sum \prod a_{l+j} x$$
the indexing is mod n. E.g., for $n=4$
$$4 + (a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3)x + (a_0a_1+a_1a_2+a_2a_3+a_3a_0)x^2 + \\(a_0a_1a_2+a_1a_2a_3+a_2a_3a_0+a_3a_0a_1a_2)x^3 + 4a_0a_1a_2a_3 x^4$$
The patterns should be obvious. (The factors of n may not be necessary or even the 0th and nth terms)
Do these have a name?

Symmetric Sum is related : https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Symmetric_sum

These functions are called elementary symmetric polynomials.

@JensSchwaiger These are not symmetric, they are cyclic. One is not allowing out of order permutations. E.g., 0132 does not exist as an multi-index. Any two indices adjacent have to differ by 1 modulo n. Every coefficient has n terms rather than n choose k.

We can use the cyclic sum notation
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}f\left(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3\right)}
&=f\left(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3\right)+f\left(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_0\right)\\
&\qquad+f\left(a_2,a_3,a_0,a_1\right)+f\left(a_3,a_0,a_1,a_2\right)
\end{align*}
replacing the arguments $a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3$ systematically in a cyclic manner.
Here we  take
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{f\left(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3\right)=1+a_0x+a_0a_1x^2+a_0a_1a_2x^3+a_0a_1a_2a_3x^4}
\end{align*}
